# How can I use gdal warp on a .sid to create an .tif of the same resolution?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, mrsid

I’m trying to convert a .sid to .tif in OSGeo and was left this script by a former co-worker. I’m not very savvy in scripting, so I’m unsure of my translation.

First, I set the directory. The conversion command includes "-tr  ": set output file resolution (in target georeferenced units). Does “target georeferenced units” here mean the units of the source data? The .sid I am trying to convert is in degrees.

If I wanted the output to be the same resolution as the source, wouldn’t the following numbers be 1 and 1? Or is it asking what the size (in the units specified in the source data) of each pixel should be in the output?

If it’s the latter, then if the source data was in degrees, with 30 cm resolution, this script:

```
for /r %a in (*.sid) do gdalwarp -tr .000005 .000005 %a %~dnpa.vrt && for /r %b in (*.vrt) do gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co TILES=YES %b %~dpnb.tif && del %a && del %b
```

…would mean each pixel in the output is .000005 degrees?

How can I calculate what the -tr resolution needs to be to keep the output as the same resolution as the input?

Comment: If you want the same resolution you don't need to include `gdalwarp`, just use `gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co TILES=YES your_input.sid your_output.tif`

Comment: `“target georeferenced units”` means the pixel size in degrees if the target projection is using degrees as units like EPSG:4326 does. And if the target projection is based on metres or feet then -tr means pixel size metres or feet, respectively. In your script the gdalwarp part is obviously written to make the pixel size uniform. Perhaps the source data has been heterogeneous. Because there is no change of projection it is unnecessary to use gdalwarp. Gdal_translate can also change pixel size. But it is not wrong to use gdalwarp that way.